# manually enter the date by typing in keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I am using rc calendar package https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-calendar
- when i try to remove 9 from 2019 and change it to 2018 itys working.
- but when delete the whole date 1/15/2019 its not allowing.
- I am trying to manually enter the date by typing in keyboard.
- all my date changes are in the method handleChange(date)
- Can you tell me how to fix it, so that in future I will fix it myself.
- Providing my sandbox and code snippet below.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tch9tf?file=demo.js

```
class CalendarPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      date: new Date(),
      dateValue: '',
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(date) {
    console.log(date);
    console.log(moment(date));
    if (moment(date) != 'Invalid date') {

      if (date != null) {
        console.log('valid Date');
        this.setState({
          date: date
        });
        this.setState({
          dateValue: moment(date).format('MM-DD-YYYY')
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          dateValue: ''
        });
      }
    }
  }



  render() {
    const calendar = (<Calendar />);
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
          animation="slide-up"
          value={moment(this.state.date)}
          disabled={false}
          calendar={calendar}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        >{
            ({ value }) => {
              return (
                <input value={this.state.dateValue} />
              )
            }
          }</DatePicker>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you want to fix ?

Comment: @Treycos I am trying to delete all the values in the text field and then enter manually the date by typing in textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a handler for your  component. 
Maybe like:

```
<input value={this.state.dateValue} onChange={(e)=>{this.manualDateEntryFromInputHandler(e)}}/>
```

Then, in your class implement your handler for that `onChange` event:

```
manualDateEntryFromInputHandler(e) {
    let inputValue = e.target.value
    let dateValue = inputValue
    let date = moment(inputValue) 
    this.setState({date, dateValue})
}
```

I do not know of course what you want to achieve, but at least it'll let you to manually enter the date.

Comment: I updated your sandbox with @WavyWalk answer 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qnmfnz?file=demo.js